# How to send data from the same port after listening in c++?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

When I do the following steps to receive a message and send a reply, it fails.
I am using TCP. I need the program to send data from the same port it received from.

```
bind()
listen()
accept()
recv()
connect()//it fails to connect here using the same socket.<br>
send()
```

Comment: You are a TCP server - clients do the connecting, not you!  Get rid of the connect attempt.  Just send to the same socket you used for the recv call.

Comment: I want to send to another client from the same port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have a problem in understanding the way tcp works. There is a server and a client. The server waits for connections, and the client makes connections. Once a connection is established, the server and the client can communicate bi-directional (i.e. both can send and recive messages). Of course, their role might change, but this is the way it works. So, the server does:

```
bind()
listen()
accept()
recv()
send()
```

It is stuck at accept() until a client performs connect() on the port that the server is listening to.

As my explanation is pretty brief, I suggest you read [this](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) tutorial about linux sockets.